# ¿Como copiar una estructura de divs estilizados al portapapeles con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un sitio web que pretende generar firmas para correo electrónico ó para usar en Word, tengo el problema de que no logro copiar los estilos y los divs en si de manera correcta.

Lo siguiente seria mi funcion que uso para copiar al portapapeles que me esta fallando y en html he puesto donde se encuentra el elemento que se quiere copiar estilizado que lleva el id firma:

como mayor detalle estoy usando bootstrap y blade en esta vista.

```
function CopyToClipboard() 
  {
    var elm = document.getElementById("firma");
    
    if(window.getSelection)
    {
      // other browsers
      var selection = window.getSelection();
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(elm);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
      document.execCommand("Copy");
      alert("Se copio la firma al portapapeles");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("No se pudo copiar la firma.");
    }

  }
```

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div id="firma" class="card">            
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="row">
                <div id="firma1_divider" class="col-md-4 px-0">
                  <img src="{{URL::asset('img/profile.png')}}" style="width:96px;height:96px; overflow:hidden;" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="perfil">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 px-0">          
                      <div id="firma1_nombre" class="col-md-12 font-weight-bold py-1">Jhon Doe</div>
                      <div id="firma1_titulo" class="col-md-12 pb-1">Ingeniero en Sistemas</div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 py-1">
                        <a id="firma1_telf" href="https://wa.me/59176543210" style="color: #82c91e;"><img src="{{ URL::asset('img/whatsapp.png') }}" width="26px" height="26px" alt="whatsapp logo"></a>                            
                        <img src="{{ URL::asset('img/map-marker.png') }}" width="20px" height="20px" alt="ubicacion"><span id="firma1_geo"> Santa Cruz, Bolivia</span>
                      </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block my-3" onclick="CopyToClipboard();"> Copiar al Portapapeles</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>        
    </section>
```

esta seria imagen de la pagina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando intento pegar a word o al cliente de correo nativo de windows 10 me lo muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se dan cuenta se copia todo menos los estilos de la tarjeta ó firma como los margenes y el espaciado e inclusive en el correo no me muestra las imagenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya logre encontrar esta solución: primeramente la función que me funciono para copiar al portapapeles es esta:

```
function CopyToClipboard() 
  {
    var elm = document.getElementById("firma");
    elm.classList.remove("col-md-12");
    elm.classList.add("col-md-10");
    if(window.getSelection)
    {          
      var selection = window.getSelection();
      var range = document.createRange();

      range.selectNodeContents(elm);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
      document.execCommand("Copy");//copia al portapapeles

      elm.classList.remove("col-md-10");
      elm.classList.add("col-md-12");
      selection.removeAllRanges();//deselecciona la firma, es decir quita el focus de la seleccion

      alert("Se copio la firma al portapapeles");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("No se pudo copiar la firma.");
    }

  }
```

y segundo: al parecer es mejor utilizar tablas para este tipo de cosas y las imagenes deben estar en base64 para el caso de los correos para que se muestren:

```
<section id="firmas_generadas" class="container py-5">
      <div class="row">         
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <table id="firma" class="col-md-12">   
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 0px;">
                  <img id="firma1_foto" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgCAYAAADimHc4AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwAADqYAAAOpgAABdwnLpRPAAAAAZiS0dEAP8A/wD/oL2nkwAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAGzFJREFUeNrtnXmQXMWd5z/53qu7+j7Ul+4TIYEkLoEAcxoERqwXswZzmLUA2+PYwzETu7bHgXGY3fHsjGdnNsbHzHB4DAx4DAxgg8CwAhyAwFy6kARCR6ulvrurq7qqXr0rc/941YdQd1d1d3WLiNU3oqO7q169zPf9Zv7yl7/8ZRacwimcwimcwv+vECe7AhPh2vllAEFgLXAZ0JKv8zFgC7AD8J5rHRz5TNOc4b+fa+862Y9QEJ9ZAfLkVwDfBe4Cqj91SQfwj8DfAQmgCtiQ/6nLv/Ym8KqChAb8bpRQnxV8JgXIkx8H/hc++cY4l0rgIeAp4E+BC4DwqPctfBHuA/UKCPXcZ0yEkybAtfPiIDRAVQDnAucAlUAPPmlXAH8OBArcygay+c+Ohw7gP+ObLYUiB8jnjpx8MU6KAF+YV44UCgEXAffgt9zoqEsG8ImPlbDYdqAVX7AdwJPAW4B9MnvFrAtw7YIyUACsB34JLD9Jzz4APAj8T6DvZImgz3aByypCAIuBB4AzTspT+wjjN4Jy4JVllSFnf9Ke9Upos1nYtfPKhv68Fd/mn2wI4A5gE8A1C8tnvQKzKgBCgO/dXDrrTzo+IsAtQFhINeuFz64AvvGvAJpn/Uknxpn4k7xZx6wJ4Pv2QgMWcrzH81lAJbAGiFw7v5xNLeHp3W0SmHEv6Jp5MYTQATUf3xf/D/g94LM0CVSMzJx/quBlAe5seEYz7gUtqwwDXIzv9dyA73V8lsgnX58IsAz4goBqhHh3WUUwN9Oe0YyaoOtWNhI+46xaNO37wNkz+iSlQyXw7cCCxd+Z9+Lb5Zt/928zWtiMtMQ7t/wWhEKLl69M/fpXPxp87qnr8bxZn3NMGUoRmLfAqfr6t581GpvvUY6zBxT3b9xU8qJK3gPu3PIsoHQUt8nkwJNuT+e/x3FmlHylFFLK0t1QCNz2owGn7dANSnpPgfoyAt1/ttKipALkKxgC/gTE3yrHXuF1z2xMXkpJLB5jwdKFCCFKJoRyHNz2o6DUcuBnKL4FhEotQskEyFcsih+//zGo6undcQxSlDruBwENzQ3c8s3b+bP/8R1u/NpNtCyYi2EY/vvTLc/zhv6sBv4i/2zRUopQkjFgFPk/AP4Lfi8ApUg+/E9kX98K2tStkFIKJRVLT1/K2vXr8DyJEIJ4WZzTzzqDxpZGhD/Lpr+njz3bP+Sxf3yUZGJg+PXJMyOovP1uIhsuBTkshAX8b+BHQLYUY8K0bfMos/Nd/EWR0MjddVAKa+cHox9iUqQjIBqLcua5a/jibTew+uwzWLhsIQuXLWTeonnU1NYMhTgAiMajzFs0H8d22Ldrr79kM1kNlEKvqSO+8Xq0WHz0Owb+2oUA3lx3683e+48+dvIEuPP5ZxAKHSG+hR/XP2EKqVdUYu/fh9fbfRxRE0FKSW19LedcfC5rzz+LKzZdyYYrL6KisgIp5YgJQhAMhY5v5QqEEMxfsoBk/wCtBw/jeR4ir0KxPSJ28eVEzl4/HmfnAoMo3ll3681qOiJMWQC/5QvQxB349rHshIuEhr13N9k3X0VZVlECCCFYvmo5N9xxIxdeeTGLly+murYaTdPGuL1GKBwak9RAMMDyVctpmttMIBjEsW00XUNKWXigNgxil16F0TIPxh5LAsB5CA4JJXavve0mPnjk8SnxaEzpU8MMcCbwHcZaDhQCZWZIv/QcMtHvm6MCCAQCfP7fXcUFl19IeWX5cGufCpRSxMvL+NzGy7jgsgtJ9PWTzWR5+pGn+ONrb6HpE/gfjoP59uuEVp6BiETGE6ES+IESao9QYudUKZySF5S3+1X4g9GyMS8SAqf9KE7bIdAKF6OUIhwJs+a8tZRXlZfEnVRKIT0P3dCpa6hn0fLFrFq3emLyATQN68MdWHt2Fuq1K4D7gKqpekaTFiBfUBB/0L1m3AuFwOvpRuVyRZkeJRWN85qoqK5ESYUQ4rifyUIIgZb/Gfq853qcteFsVpxxGp47sVOgbIvcjnfBdQsVdQ2+FQhORYSpzgM2At+g0BiiimzFSlFRXcGl11yGZhgkkmk6e/pp7+yjqydBcjCDJyW6pk0ohiYEuqbhOC59iRRHO3o40t5NR1cfA6k0tuNQU1fLLV+/jdPXrkI3Jqq+wO3uQtkFxy49z8VlUyFyUmNAXuEw8FXGGnQ/RapeXYsIBP2HGPMRfS/RFTrhphZe3XGAZ/6wHcu2UUrhuh45y0EIQXl5nPXrVnLeuhVUlseAkRauaQLPU7R39/HyH97lve37yGRNBIpIOIRh6GiaRjQaYU59DWtWL+PGu2/lwb/+OUcPt019rjCCcuA24NU7tzybm8z8oGgBNr/w26HB6EbgqoIfUAqjZT6BhYux9+4GzfdAhkxKzlN0ZV0Sloel6VTpBs01UdYubSASDqLn7fSQCL0Dg+zd+zHPvPgG5eVxjPz7gUAQ3dDJmjlsy2LVkmYuPXcZVRVxwiH/PkopHNcjk81xtKOPf3joCQ4d6SbX20OZ8KiLGAQ0X4ThOqIw6uYggqHxBuFP43r8vKNH7tzybNGBu6Ld0LNuuRmgEfhbYH4xnxGhEFo0hrV7B0Fd47zPrScQDNLd1cuuhM3hQYeU7bF29WLu/vLlNNVXEQkHMQwdw9DRNY1AwCAWDVFbVcayBY1kTZN/fmIrSsG85no0XefVNz5g78eHufumK9hw1gqqKuPDLV9ogmDAIBQ0iMcizG2sZUFLPVtefY+DnQm6TQ+poDasEw6HWX/pBeQyJtmcQ/zqTQTmzi9WgCAwD/gtkC52blCUAJu3PDs0mbwD+BqTmFsKw8B89y02bFjHl/7jl6mpr+HA3v1IK4clFZaCm669gKULGvHyno8Qgu7eBFtfe4+PD7RRU1VONBJGATWVZWzf18o3v7qJP/nqJq7beBF9iRSeY/OljecPu62mafHyK++w7e2dBIMBamsqAZBKUV4WobNngF0ftdIcDzA3HiCowVkbzuGuP/0G1XXV7Bt0iVx5LSJQKDHvOMzBT/56Z91tN/F+EXODokxQnu0WYDOTGbiFhnP0CEHb5Mzz1mIYBouXL6GppZGB3n5CeohdSZeq8vhQshYAuZzFi//3bfZ9fASAdDrLDZsuIRQKEgoahIMB0hkTqRRSKtIZk4qyKLqmIfMz5Dff2slLW9/G8zxa2zrZfPsmmpvqUcr3sOqqy6kMapxWGSKkC4SuccFlG4jGoqxat5rmQ30kAsFiW/8Q9DxHz6DE0WI+MBkv6Domm0glwEsOYAhBNB5DKYWmaVTWVCGlIqZDhQFZa2TZTwhBJpujs6sfTfMH2M7ufsycjQBsx0XXdea3zEEp3/NZuqgF23Hx8mklnudx5GgXnifRdZ1kMk13b2JksFWQzdmsO20BsXAAx3Gpa6inecFcpJSEwiHCZhppZosOn4zCGcAlxV5csAfc6ZsfTcH5kxQMAC0cxvY8LDPn/69rXH7dlUgpyaYzlKVsunuTw9crpYhFw9TWVDCQTANQV1tJJBICAcnBLJUVZSxZ0IRU/kz57DXL+f3WbeQsm2g4iK7rNDfVsWPXfjzPo6qynLraquHW7Hoevf0pvnL7DcRdk/Yj7Zx3yXoamht878txyWWyx/XKSUAHzkeJR+/c8qwqNBgXZYIULAEunHRVlMJonosTCNF2sJVFyxejlKK+sZ6b7voKAtix7zCPPflivmX7+obDQa66/Dwa53yCEIIzVy0hFAwgELQe6+WcNSuoqSpHKd9rWbpoLosWtNDe3c/SBY0oBeefuxqAgWSalSsW0thQi8ybn/6BNGg6689ZRUtTHTI/8RvygHo6u+l3FNr4YYhCuBqhlgD7C104oQCbHhtekL4MWDDpakhJoKEZfdFStr/1PudcvJ5INDJsioSAVcvm09RYT1tHH4vm1SOlQiloaqilqaF2lJYK03Zo701xy5euYpQ1IRIOcvXl63njzXdZMr8RpRRlZTE+f/n6fFkCmTdPmibYe+AoG847k+bGWjxPDt9/CB+89T5mzRzioRBMLSSyED/7r6AAE5qU+kod/MjfFUx18SYQIL7hUo509bN923vHTXqUgmDQYNNVG+joG8TM2WiaP08YCTmPhJDf33OY1SuXsHBuwzChAJ4nOXfdaVRUVrHvwNHhe4wWb2g86e1P4aFz/caLTmjcuq7TdrCVbe/vJbhi1ZQeNw8BXA4ECoUnJnRD1916M/iZzN/FTymcPFR+QlM3h9Z336PcENQ31IMgTzRUV5YRDIbYse8wbR296EKA8CdhqcEsn7R2sWv/MVpamrny4rMwDL/djA5HG7rOooXNfHTwGDv2HMS2HXRNIJXCzDm0d/WzY+8RTFdwxSXraW6sGxbZcz00XePQvk/49b+9RN+aDYSXr5yq+RlCDHgGSEw0J5iwVefVuxH4F6YbutY03N5u3CcfoUWZVNXVctUXr6Ksony4hSYHs+zae5DWo51Ylp03D4LqqnLOWLmYRfMa0bQRXjRdp6yifHitQAiB47h8+NEhdu05QDI1CEr518VjrFg6n9WnLSYSCQ7b/YH+AX7z4ONIz6NVRMicfTGhBYuLj2ONDwe4GXhyooF4XFJHdZ110yYfQEqM2nrSkTK2b32DcCzGGeecSXllRT6tRFEej3LReavZcM4qXNdDKoWhaxi6jkINjw/jQSmFYeisW72MtauX4bounifRNI1AQEcIgefJYfMlNEFH2zG2bX0DWzeo/fb3CC9aMnoxfjoI5Ll7cvOW3/LAxuvGvKiQWxnGT1otGYzqGnTDwLZtOo92HNcHlVJ4nu9a6rpGwMiTJuVxNr8QvPyql5YPZei6hpRqeMAdKRA+2rUPyzSJrj2bQPO8UpE/hDVASEzgzxYSoBpYVLLqKAivORu9tg7leRz+5BCuUzDePmNwXZe2g63oTS3EP38dIhgsdRGL8BeuxkUhAeqBmpJVR0mMphbiV12HFg7zyYcf09vZM+Z670xD0zS6j3ZwZNCm6pbNGE0tU3U5J0ItPofj16PADZooFPefAiIbLqXyljtJB6O8tuUVbDNX/IxfKRhyUZXMj8hq5HcREIAjFduyOt71XyG0YtV0PZ7xEMePII+LQoPrHPwwa0khDIPIhs9hLFjE7u3v0HCwiwtXzkMUIFBoOvHahRjBkclcMBxCy6unlMIebEe6uQnvI4FtScm74TkYTZTC4xkPIQr0gEICVM5UzZCSQNNcjKYW/ug5VNkWqwP2hBIoKdEDYarmnokQJ3Zee7ADK9k2YbEa8M6g4vcJhSNnfKOCoMBe50IClNz8HAcl/QinZvBKTiOnBGuCFgHGMyaKZMdePDtL+ZylBKNVCE1DOlmf/FQbStqMRasAXAVvDSpeTihyM0/+6KLHRSEBQswCBJBWGq/koiSlxoWhHGGhxhRBSY/B7gNkEkcJRcqJlpWBtPJmRzAe+TkJWwcUrycVjvrsbNEpJMCsuScC8IB37DAOgs+FTGJCMaZ1FgLpWliZPoKGi6brjEepBmQkbOlX/DGlppQqOpMoJIBzMiq13Q7R7+mcG8qx2HDGIUz4my4ncJ8UsC+r+EMSPjH9HvVZIh8KC5A+WRU77BkkMyFipGgoCyEmMVcQQiBdj8O9KZ7MxuhX+mxviC4ahQRIFnWXGYAAHAWJRBI9rVFRXUEoMvGQNBTGzgxm6D7WybG0jVW5aAqriiWFNdGbhQToBtwirpsR+DlEGtl0FitnE41HiJXHhkPQQ0Pu0GpWJp0h0dPPQN8ATs5CxMpLkXQ1Hdh5DsdFIWI78A9Dmv1TLIBYJE5z5VLMIx9hmhapgUEyg1nCkRDReJRQJIxumFg5i2R/knRqEMfOZ9JVVVC/YCXhAchY1rTrMkVkgc6JLigkQBf+uTqzLoBSirnxcpqbl5HWXZI97aQG0riOSyadJZsx/WVNTeC5HkpKEIJINEJtQy3VDS2oqtOosw7TV2SC8Aygn2n2gB78RKN5s1XjoaXeHMprjJdpoXCFRvOZaBpEYglyWYucaWHlLDzPAwWhcIhoWYx4WYyyijJC8SqIL0ILxKiKRL1Mf68qE76vOsvnoRwGeie6YEIB4uXhdDqV+xD/aLEZxRDxaSm9/XbO/cTJaRe4ti5QGNEaIvUrUd4OAsEgZRVxXNfDk4pY3B8TAsEAmqahhAGx+RDwV1D3Wab2fHrAWRmKeosCIT2mabMpxG6lyE7kwI371v0bN5FO5QA+mGniBaik9Nz3clnr+fSAei+XCQ24bvCImfWJUopAfA7ByrnkN4FhBAxC0TDRsvjwoKyUgnADBKsAhacUbTlTpDw3+LaZDj6fGVAf5LLWoPQcAWqGjZICtgsB/3T1FJYkR+EdfFNUV2riPZCdruO2OpZoc2yRkl6IUXOlw9kMrpLDG+zC1YuRTg47dWz4ERUj2ROE6iDSMHx/0/Noz5ngx1nFgOcF3vUyxidOzm0xgu6CQEjVGwFD9xPPSo2uPHcTohgB9gO7KdEpV/k9AarXc93dlilbHctwlBozO+NozsT0JDFd92exeohI/WlIN4ebGW1aFQQqfdMjRkJ5ac+l2zohNC0GPC8w4Jl8bOe8hYGQszIUEdW6EdBKa5p2AgenKYAAVBp4bboCCJ8W1ee57h7LlIcdW88pOeHMqsfOMeg6xIY3+Ck0I0K0fiXpY+8hvZy/kKLHfPK14DD5QggGHIeE64zrAdlK6R/ZOa3Vsb2FwZC9MhjRqnXdoDRCvApkERPPwSd89/6Rlfzn8c3QlInvdB37TTPtvphJin12LpRTcmLxhaDPtumxreEFlyER9HAlkdplCM1AaAbE5oERZ3QQWwBdli9goSrmlDT2Wmbw95mkeMNMu52uY6vpjRFdwAsA91/9hQkvLHaGuwt4G/hCkdcPk5CW0t1tZeXHdk6zlJrUjDrtuXRYuTHSMhTBihY8z0IFg4hQ9QnbWQXQYZlYxWc5iEHpGXsskwN2zl0ejFinhyJGXNOMKfSG14APi7mwYIwqdLAHIAe8W/STAI5Scp+ds17IDKhdlhmYLPkAtpR0nWjDEULgeh6/euJl9dDjL0jPk+rTIQcFtOfM/H6BycFSythpZUMvZJJyr52zHKW8SfaG1wC7mG1KBUn56bc2DyVpPYW/O2bcSVl+gJVtju3utkzR4doBOZ01BaWwPpWpMJQn9NOf/1z+1V/+pdCEELoRUF+74w6RN3fDAnRaucmWeFxRCc8NvpkdlK0By1sZjHgtgaChFfaYDgKvFFtIceT4CQi7gSfGrS2QkdLdZqadrdmUfmy65OfR74ysEwv8dPSHHn7Y+5uf/ESY2azIZDLivvvuE4//5jfHpW4ppXBKkOkgQWtz7MDWbErfZqbtrJKFesOv02b13mLvXxRB91+zCaGhgF8BJ2y9EUCf5zqvZFNyj2UGx3Mrp4KjZhZPKX8w1wSPPv20d9+992rpVGqYh2QiIe75/vfFsy+95A3lGHlKkSo8ABcNRyl9j2WGXs0Men2ea48jwmHgkXikv+hdkpNqoVKIncAvYGSl0EPJDy3TeimTEh2uE6TEi05tZpZc/qibX7Yd5t6jB7wU6oSRtU958nutH/O77nZ0IcjJoUlYSSGOuXbwpUxKfGiZlnd8PosH/CxnB/dMpt8VLcD9Gzeh+a7G/eQHZAHqQ8t03jLTgUHpzciaQaeVI+26PNPVzl/s/5DEiiUBNl3joGkjD6/riuuvlR3zW/R79u7k9f5eMp5Hjz0zYehB6QXeMtOBj6ycLUaGndeBh8JBmwcmsVF7Kja6C3hcgOz3J1V6KWz9mBCChGPz8LFW/nzfTnoty3/xsouDnL5ipBesWe1y8QU6wKFshj/bu50XejpJOc6MhaElaLssUyQ8zxb+otUvgd7JUjGpq4fsmo74Z0epJ3daJmkpZ3S1rM+x+esD+2i38jF9pSAa1mmYM1JuS5MiEtFQfqBuX3qQH368m35nZg9dHZRecKeVxVHqX3XE0z5Hk5oqTX6p8f6Nm1j4xCP9Vbp+z2HHOg2Y1l6eQvCUH9U8/kUpyWRshk7o6u7xD4sYNRlIOLOS0CEOOdbeuKbfOyi9gf033DLpG0zJdBzKmbxvmfscpe7FXzGbXTiOpC8x8n9fQmDbs3/2PPQ7Sv3gfSu7f785tQSSqdnuW+8ayiZ+Bvg/+DZwdiAEZLKSRGLEuCcGBOmMmuVlRwf/W55+h1Jw69endJOpD543bwaf+L8Bpnd04GQgBCRTksHMSN3TGUimZlMABTwM/AyQeS6mhOl5L37BSeC/458SMvMQQH9CYVsjdbcsjf7EbArwNPA9YHA65EMp3Ee/Ah3At/BN0syjs1viyZG6Swmd3WqGNll8Gv8C/Cega7rkQ6n8d78ibcB/xV87mDlIpejq/nQatKCrW5TkvOLxofAb2H8DjpWCfCjpBCoAfizkLuBR/Kl56eF6kt6+E1/v7YOZ2/Dn4sfBvkEJyYdSCnDz7UM9oR2/i/4YSA2/729Ln95eICEgl1P09p8Y7OtLaJjm9McBpTyO35qQBH6IfyZ2ZynJh5kIIfgVTOQr/Q1gPwI0y/O0jO1OO1SXTnskUyfeJZUSDKanJ4AAPWPnNHv4TMuPgLsR/BhIlpp8mKkYzs2bQeBgeY8BNyDEC1rGcvXM2NuHiidIwEBSYZon1ts0YWBgmhUXaIOWrqUthSae9euu/hWFOxPkw0xmPd+Ur/BjD+wiErgj0J3+olsTvQv/y5mnpoIQ0NOrsO0xdug5gu5eOU0TpFBqZ6Bz8CF3Qc0TDOZ6uenOGaMIZmML0s2bib52oMv84Td/4dTGv4hSf4eftDoFepSis3u8jS6Crmm5or0o9VdufdmXzB997xfV97/ZO1OtfjRmZeNI9if3gqgCTRzBd+M24YdvJyeElIqe3rF34gH09PlBucmhB/8rtjYB31eG1oYQ9D/909mgZpY3XvgtyuGxB94A/oi/uHMJ/kGwZ1HoG/ZsW9I9QbJxTy9YtiIcKmSH0sD7wIvAVuA9wJmNFv9pnJSdL8NCPP7gG5RF3yCV+Xv8M+muw/9O+MX4X6w2AiEgayoSifF7bWJAkMlAJDzW0QNZ4AD+ytUzwDYCKoWtwVe+dlJogJMlwBBuGn7wJI898Bz+0b91+AP1Bfnfy4E5CBEjNShJZ8YXIJMVpAYVdbUuSmXwd6d8BGzHJ34Hfr7+tAJopcTJFWA0fEIk0MWvH3yBgPEClhPEF2QuQrSQNatwXA1/2h1l5BwL/3vlHcclk1UI0YcfGmkD0UuZsEmr0YKfwimcwimcwimcdPw/zTbjzI85l9cAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMTktMDQtMDlUMTE6NTY6MzErMDE6MDBMlZH3AAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDE5LTA0LTA5VDExOjU2OjMxKzAxOjAwPcgpSwAAAEZ0RVh0c29mdHdhcmUASW1hZ2VNYWdpY2sgNi43LjgtOSAyMDE5LTAyLTAxIFExNiBodHRwOi8vd3d3LmltYWdlbWFnaWNrLm9yZ0F74sgAAAAYdEVYdFRodW1iOjpEb2N1bWVudDo6UGFnZXMAMaf/uy8AAAAYdEVYdFRodW1iOjpJbWFnZTo6aGVpZ2h0ADUxMsDQUFEAAAAXdEVYdFRodW1iOjpJbWFnZTo6V2lkdGgANTEyHHwD3AAAABl0RVh0VGh1bWI6Ok1pbWV0eXBlAGltYWdlL3BuZz+yVk4AAAAXdEVYdFRodW1iOjpNVGltZQAxNTU0ODA3MzkxUirmgwAAABN0RVh0VGh1bWI6OlNpemUAMzYuM0tCQsEel2MAAABTdEVYdFRodW1iOjpVUkkAZmlsZTovLy4vdXBsb2Fkcy81Ni9MempoVjJ3LzE4NzkvaWNvbmZpbmRlci0xMC1hdmF0YXItMjc1NDU3NV8xMjA1MjEucG5nuLHvOgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" style="width:96px;height:96px; overflow:hidden;" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="perfil">
                </td>
                <td id="firma1_divider" style="border-left:3px solid rgb(0, 123, 255)">
                    <div class="col-md-12 py-1"><b id="firma1_nombre">Jhon Doe</b></div>
                    <div id="firma1_titulo" class="col-md-12 pb-1">Ingeniero en Sistemas</div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 py-1">
                      <a id="firma1_telf" href="https://wa.me/59176543210" >
                      <img src="data:image/png;base64, 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" width="26" height="26" alt="whatsapp logo"></a>
                      <a id="firma1_linkedin" href="https://linkedin.com/in/jhon-doe" >
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="24" height="24" alt="linkedin"></a>
                      <a id="firma1_github" href="https://github.com/jhondoe" >
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="24" height="24" alt="github"></a>
                      <img id="firma1_geo" src="data:image/png;base64, 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" width="24" height="24" alt="ubicacion" title="Santa Cruz, Bolivia" role="button">
                    </div>
                </td>                    
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block my-3" onclick="CopyToClipboard();"> Copiar al Portapapeles</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
```

Aqui estan las capturas actualizadas y la demo de la solución:

Vista del Html de la Firma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Implementación en Microsoft Word

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Implementación en la Aplicacion de correo de windows

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

Cuando copias el HTML de tu sitio a Outlook, MS Word u otro destino, sólamente estás copiando el HTML presente en el DOM. Así que clases como `col-md-4`, `card`, `card-header` no tienen ningún efecto en otros programas porque el CSS asociado sólamente existe en tu página web.

Para lograr un efecto más cercano a lo que deseas, en el HTML copiado deberás insertar los estilos a cada elemento dentro de su respectivo atributo `style`. Luego podrás usar la opción "Pegar con formato" en programas como MS Word.

```html
<div style="width:40%;">
    <div style="border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:5px;">
    <div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;">
        <div style="display:block">
        <div style="width:40%;display:inline-block">
            <!-- Imagen -->
        </div>
        <div class="width:60%;display:inline-block">
            <!-- Contenido -->
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Incluso así, no hay ninguna garantía de que las firmas lucirán igual en tu sitio web que en otros programas, principalmente en clientes de correo, que a veces usan su propio motor de renderizado, muy diferente al de navegadores web modernos. Aún cuando se utilice un navegador moderno para visualizar los correos, es muy posible que el servidor haya cambiado el HTML antes de mostrarlo al usuario.

Mi recomendación es cambiar el enfoque un poco y ofrecer la opción de exportar la firma como imagen, para incluirla en correos como un adjunto (Una práctica común en firmas de correo).

Comment: Efectivamente, si quiere que se mantenga exactamente igual tendrá que usar una imagen, pues no hay garantía de que se vaya a mostrar igual a como se ve con css si no. Si se hace la firma en un canvas es posible luego pasarlo a imagen y permitirle al usuario descargarla

Comment: Si la hay, pero hay que replicar los estilos que necesita el outlook, ya que usa a word, para renderizar su Html, yo en lo personal he usado (https://beefree.io/editor/)[https://beefree.io/editor/] para generar correos compatibles, y funciona bien, pero son líneas y validaciones inmensas para generar un html sencillo.